# Allowing user access to mailman python files from root?

Tags: non-root-user, acl

I just got my first managed VPS, and am taking a crash course in administering users. I normally do most things on my local computer as root. It is running centos-5-x86_64.

What I'm trying to do is give one of my user accounts access to command line for cPanel-based mailman install. Namely I want to give him access to all the python scripts in /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/

How would I go about doing this? ACL? Or just add them to the mailman group? I'm completely unsure about what to do for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving them sudo access for a limited set of commands?  See `man sudo` for details.

Note: you should get into the habit of using sudo for administration and not logging in as root.